# How to insert long text (>3K chars) in columns with unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, text, b-tree

There are [some problems](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/index-max-row-size-error) with inserting text in postgres that is too long. when I have a simple table with text, I can insert text as long as I like (I tested up to 40K chars). However, when I add a `unique` constraint I begin to encounter a strange `btree` problem, see the minimal working example (MWE) below

**MWE:**

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                             
 N=4096 # Aiming for a URL of length 4,096 characters                        
 DB_NAME='foo'                                                               
 # Generate random N character alphanumeric string of lenght 4,096           
 URL="http://www.$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w $(($N-15)) | head -n 1).com"
                                                                             
 # Case 1 we have a table ('website') which has a single column with no      
 # constraints                                                               
 TABLE_NAME='website'                                                        
 sudo -u postgres psql -c "drop database if exists $DB_NAME;"                
 sudo -u postgres psql -c "create database $DB_NAME;"                        
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "drop table if exists $TABLE_NAME;"    
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "create table $TABLE_NAME (url text);" 
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "insert into $TABLE_NAME (url) values ('$URL');"
                                                                             
                                                                             
 # Case 2 we have a table ('website2') which has a single column which must be
 # unique                                                                    
 TABLE_NAME='website2'                                                       
 sudo -u postgres psql -c "drop database if exists $DB_NAME;"                
 sudo -u postgres psql -c "create database $DB_NAME;"                        
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "drop table if exists $TABLE_NAME;"    
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "create table $TABLE_NAME (url text unique);"
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "insert into $TABLE_NAME (url) values ('$URL');"
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./test.sh                                                                 
 DROP DATABASE                                                                                                                                                                                         
 CREATE DATABASE                                                             
 NOTICE:  table "website" does not exist, skipping                           
 DROP TABLE                                                                  
 CREATE TABLE                                                                
 INSERT 0 1                                                                  
 DROP DATABASE                                                               
 CREATE DATABASE                                                             
 NOTICE:  table "website2" does not exist, skipping                          
 DROP TABLE                                                                  
 CREATE TABLE                                                                
 ERROR:  index row size 4112 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index "website2_url_key"
 DETAIL:  Index row references tuple (0,1) in relation "website2".           
 HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.           
 Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

**Question:** What should I do if I have extremely long text (>3K chars)?

1. Is there some way to disable this btree error?
2. Should I remove the `unique` constraint and check at the application level only?
3. Should I compress all my URLs?
4. Is it simply impossible to achieve this via PSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better yet, cast the md5 to type `uuid`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_url_index ON $TABLE_NAME ((md5(url)::uuid));  -- parens required
```

Makes the index smaller and faster. See:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684)
- [Character varying index overhead & length limit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69164/3684)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution over at [UNIQUE constraint on large VARCHARs - PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94205/unique-constraint-on-large-varchars-postgresql)

**Solution:**

```
 N=4096 # Aiming for a URL of length 4,096 characters                        
 DB_NAME='foo'                                                               
 # Generate random N character alphanumeric string of lenght 4,096           
 URL="http://www.$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w $(($N-15)) | head -n 1).com"
                                                                             
 # To get over the length limitation of a text column with a unique          
 # constraint we  carry out the following                                    
 #  1) Remove UNIQUE constraint from column                                  
 #  2) Add UNIQUE constraint for md5 of column                               
 TABLE_NAME='websitemd5'                                                     
 sudo -u postgres psql -c "drop database if exists $DB_NAME;"                
 sudo -u postgres psql -c "create database $DB_NAME;"                        
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "drop table if exists $TABLE_NAME;"    
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "create table $TABLE_NAME (url text);" 
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "create unique index unique_url_index on $TABLE_NAME (md5(url));"
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "insert into $TABLE_NAME (url) values ('$URL');"                                                                                                                 
 sudo -u postgres psql -d $DB_NAME -c "insert into $TABLE_NAME (url) values ('$URL');"
```

**Output:**

```
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
NOTICE:  table "websitemd5" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_url_index"
DETAIL:  Key (md5(url))=(71bf6c554ab335360cd657d060f84c2d) already exists.
```